# Publishing/readability/style: Should definitions be put in an appendix?

Tags: notation, publishing

When writing mathematical content with the intent for publication, should definitions be put in an appendix and simply referenced to in the text, or should they be placed at the point where they are first used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both. Put them where they first turn up, and put them in an appendix so the reader who starts reading in the middle can find them.